# @html.actionlink renders wrong url

Tags: asp.net, razor, html.actionlink

I've just started to learn ASP.NET and I'm trying to create a simple navigation but somohow i get the wrong url. I've been looking for anwsers all over the place but most are about more complex url.

I'm using this for my navigation

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "index")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Domeinen", "Domain")</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

The website renders but when I click "domeinen" It brings me to

> `http://localhost:7498/Home/Domain`

instead of

```
http://localhost:7498/Domain
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it creates a url to the current controller (which is Home in your case). If you want to modify it, you can use another of this function signatures:

```
Html.ActionLink("Domeinen", "Domain", "DomainController")
```